# epoll: difference between level triggered and edge triggered when EPOLLONESHOT specified

Tags: linux, network-programming, epoll

What's the difference between level triggered and edge triggered mode, when EPOLLONESHOT specified?

There's a similar question already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173429/one-shot-level-triggered-epoll-does-epolloneshot-imply-epollet). The answer by "Crouching Kitten" doesn't seem to be right (and as I understand, the other answer doesn't answer my question).

I've tried the following:

- server sends 2 bytes to a client, while client waits in `epoll_wait`
- client returns from `epoll_wait`, then reads 1 byte.
- client re-arms the event (because of EPOLLONESHOT)
- client calls `epoll_wait` again. Here, for both cases (LT & ET), `epoll_wait` doesn't wait, but returns immediately (contrary to the answer by "Crouching Kitten")
- client can read the second byte

Is there any difference between LT & ET, when EPOLLONESHOT specified?

Comment: It would be great if you could post your code above. I believe you did what you claimed you did, but it would make the question better for the next guy who comes along.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh: unfortunately this code is part of a larger framework. But, I've just checked out kernel source code, and as I understand, there is indeed no difference between LT and ET, if EPOLLONESHOT is specified. I'll wait for some time, and if no answer arrives, I'll answer my own question.

Comment: This is what happens when you interrupt writing an answer with dinner. People find their own answers in your absence :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the bottom line answer is "there is not difference".

Looking at [the code](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/fs/eventpoll.c), it seems that the fd remembers the last set bits before being disabled by the one-shot. It remembers it was one shot, and it remembers whether it was ET or not.

Which is futile, because the fd is disabled until modified, and the next call to `EPOLL_CTL_MOD` will erase all of that, and replace with whatever the new MOD says.

Having said that, I do not understand why anyone would want both `EPOLLET` and `EPOLLONESHOT`. To me, the whole point of `EPOLLET` is that, unders certain programming models (namely, microthreads), it follows the semantics perfcetly. This means that I can add the fd to the epoll at the very start, and then never have to perform another epoll related system call.

`EPOLLONESHOT`, on the other hand, is used by people who want to keep a very strict control over when the fd is watched and when it isn't. That, by definition, is the opposite of what `EPOLLET` is used for. I just don't think the two are conceptually compatible.

Comment: What do you mean by this? "This means that I can add the fd to the epoll at the very start, and then never have to perform another epoll related system call" I think `epoll_wait` would still be called, wouldn't it?

Comment: plus, there is another combination, which doesn't seem to make sense: ET+EXCLUSIVE. What do you think about this?

Comment: Don't have much experience with it. The way I read it, `EPOLLET` is useful for microthreading, while both exclusive and oneshot are useful for multi-threading. As such, I don't think there is any inherent friction as far as when you'd want to use them.

Comment: As for your first question, I think it is too long for a comment. I know I'm (a word that begins with W that SO wouldn't let me write because it thinks I'm directing it at you) for karma points here, but if you ask "When does it make sense to use EPOLLET", I promise to give it my best shot :-) (hint hint)

Comment: @geza see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46633433/what-is-the-use-case-for-epollet for answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The other poster said "I do not understand why anyone would want both `EPOLLET` and `EPOLLONESHOT`." Actually, according to [epoll(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html), there is a use case for that:

> Since even with edge-triggered `epoll`, multiple events can be generated upon receipt of multiple chunks of data, the caller has the option to specify the `EPOLLONESHOT` flag, to tell `epoll` to disable the associated file descriptor after the receipt of an event with `epoll_wait(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is that whether EPOLL will treat the combination of EPOLLET | EPOLLONESHOT and EPOLLLT | EPOLLONESHOT as special case. As I known, it is not. EPOLL just care them seperately. To EPOLLET and EPOLLLT, the different kindly only is in function `ep_send_events`, if the EPOLLET is set, then the function will call `list_add_tail` to add the `epitem` into the ready list in `epoll_fd/eventepoll` object.
To the `EPOLLONESHOT`, the role is to disable the `fd`. So I think the different between them is the different between `ET` and `LT`. You can check the result using below codes I think

```
// server.cc
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_EVENT_NUMBER 1024

int setnonblocking(int fd)
{
    int old_option = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
    int new_option = old_option | O_NONBLOCK;
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, new_option);
    return old_option;
}

void addfd(int epollfd, int fd, bool oneshot)
{
    epoll_event event;
    event.data.fd = fd;
    event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
    if(oneshot)
        event.events |= EPOLLONESHOT;
    epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &event);
    setnonblocking(fd);
}
// reset the fd with EPOLLONESHOT
void reset_oneshot(int epollfd, int fd)
{
    epoll_event event;
    event.data.fd = fd;
    event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET | EPOLLONESHOT;
    epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, fd, &event);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc <= 2)
    {
        printf("usage: %s ip_address port_number\n", basename(argv[0]));
        return 1;
    }
    const char* ip = argv[1];
    int port = atoi(argv[2]);

    int ret = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &address.sin_addr);
    address.sin_port = htons(port);

    int listenfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    assert(listenfd >= 0);
    ret = bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address));
    assert(ret != -1);

    ret = listen(listenfd, 5);
    assert(ret != -1);

    epoll_event events[MAX_EVENT_NUMBER];
    int epollfd = epoll_create(5);
    addfd(epollfd, listenfd, false);
    while(1)
    {
        printf("next loop: -----------------------------");
        int ret = epoll_wait(epollfd, events, MAX_EVENT_NUMBER, -1);
        if(ret < 0)
        {
            printf("epoll failure\n");
            break;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < ret; i++)
        {
            int sockfd = events[i].data.fd;
            if(sockfd == listenfd)
            {
                printf("into listenfd part\n");
                struct sockaddr_in client_address;
                socklen_t client_addrlength = sizeof(client_address);
                int connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_address,
                     &client_addrlength);
                printf("receive connfd: %d\n", connfd);
                addfd(epollfd, connfd, true);
                // reset_oneshot(epollfd, listenfd);
            }
            else if(events[i].events & EPOLLIN)
            {
                printf("into linkedfd part\n");
                printf("start new thread to receive data on fd: %d\n", sockfd);
                char buf[2];
                memset(buf, '\0', 2);
                // just read one byte, and reset the fd with EPOLLONESHOT, check whether still EPOLLIN event
                int ret = recv(sockfd, buf, 2 - 1, 0);

                if(ret == 0)
                {
                    close(sockfd);
                    printf("foreigner closed the connection\n");
                    break;
                }
                else if(ret < 0)
                {
                    if(errno == EAGAIN)
                    {
                        printf("wait to the client send the new data, check the oneshot memchnism\n");
                        sleep(10);
                        reset_oneshot(epollfd, sockfd);
                        printf("read later\n");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    printf("receive the content: %s\n", buf);
                    reset_oneshot(epollfd, sockfd);
                    printf("reset the oneshot successfully\n");
                }
            }
            else 
                printf("something unknown happend\n");
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
    close(listenfd);
    return 0;
}
```

the Client is

```
from socket import *
import sys
import time

long_string = b"this is a long content which need two time to fetch"

def sendOneTimeThenSleepAndClose(ip, port):
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM);
    a = s.connect((ip, int(port)));
    print("connect success: {}".format(a));
    data = s.send(b"this is test");
    print("send successfuly");
    time.sleep(50);
    s.close();
sendOneTimeThenSleepAndClose('127.0.0.1', 9999)
```